# The most efficient way to run a simple useQuery hook when a component mounts

Tags: javascript, react.js, graphql

I have a very simple API query (using GraphQL - URQL, but the client used doesn't matter) that just fetches data and displays it on the page, and I’m trying to figure out the most efficient way to make the query not re-run whenever the component re-renders (which I assume it possibly does).

According to the [URQL docs' example](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/basics/react-preact/#run-a-first-query), it says to just use it as per option 1 below:

Option 1: simple without any other hooks (e.g. useEffect)

```
const Component = () => {
    const [{ data, error, fetching: loading }] = useQuery(…);

    if (loading) return <p>loading...</p>
    if (error) return <p>error!</p>

    return (<>…</>)
}
```

However, I wonder whether this is not 100% optimised, because would it not re-run with every re-render? Thus I was wondering whether option 2 below might be better since it should only run when the component mounts:

Option 2: run it inside a useEffect hook

```
const Component = () => {
    const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = React.useState(false);
    const [{ data, error, fetching: loading }, runQuery] = useQuery({
        pause: isMounted, // NOTE: useState rather than useRef, otherwise TS error: Type 'MutableRefObject<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'
    });

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setIsMounted(true);
        runQuery();
        return () => {
            setIsMounted(false);
        };
    }, []);

    if (loading) return <p>loading...</p>;
    if (error) return <p>error!</p>;

    return (<>…</>)
}
```

It would be great to know which option is optimal. Is option 1 suboptimal? Mind you, the fact that URQL’s docs mention this way makes me believe option 1 might be best suited, and because hooks initialise only once when the component renders for the first time; if a component re-renders, hooks don’t re-initialise to their initial values again

Does it really make any real difference? Any explanations of what the best way is and why would be very helpful. Thank you!